# A simple text based snake game in python

Tags: python, snake-game

I've written a simple text-based (can be run in terminal) snake game in python. This is a personal project and also one of my very first projects in python. I appreciate any advice or suggestion that make my code more efficient and professional.

**main.py**

```py
from game import Game

if __name__=="__main__":
    game = Game()
    game.new_game([15,15])
    game.run()
```

**game.py**

```py
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
from snake import Snake
from board import Board


class Game:
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def new_game(self, board_dim = [10, 10], level = "EASY"):

        self.snake = Snake(2, [[2,2],[2,3]], "UP", board_dim)
        self.board = Board(board_dim[0], board_dim[1], self.snake.pos)
        self.thrd  = Thread(target=self.snake.check_arrow_keys)
        self.score = 0

    def finish_game(self):
        print(f"Your score is {self.score}")
        self.thrd.join()
        exit()
        
    def run(self):

        self.thrd.start()
        while True:

            print('\033c')
            if not self.snake.status:
                break

            self.board.food_process(self.snake.normalize_pos())
            if self.board.eaten:
                self.score += 1
                self.snake.move_toward_direction(increment_size=True)
            else:
                self.snake.move_toward_direction()

            self.board.board_init(self.snake.normalize_pos())
            self.board.show_board(self.snake)
            print(f"score:{self.score}")
            sleep(.2)

        self.finish_game()
```

**board.py**

```py
from random import randint

class Board:
        
        def __init__(self, columns, rows, fill):
            self.board = [[0 for j in range(columns)] for i in range(rows)]
            self.fill  = fill
            self.col   = columns
            self.rows  = rows
            self.first = fill[-1]
            self.put_food(fill)
  
   

        def board_init(self, fill):

            self.board = [[0 for j in range(self.col)] for i in range(self.rows)]
            self.fill  = fill
            self.first = fill[-1]
            
            for i in self.fill:
                if i == self.first:
                    self.board[i[0]%self.rows][i[1]%self.col] = 2
                else:
                    self.board[i[0]%self.rows][i[1]%self.col] = 1

            self.board[self.food[0]][self.food[1]] = 3
        
        
        def food_process(self, fill):
    
            if self.check_food(fill):
                self.eaten = True
                self.put_food(fill)
            else:
                self.eaten = False
            
        def normalize_fill(self, fill):
            return [[i[0]%self.rows, i[1]%self.col] for i in fill]
            
        def check_food(self, fill):
            if self.food in self.normalize_fill(fill):
                return True

            return False

 
        def put_food(self, fill):
            
            while True:
                x,y = randint(0,self.col-1), randint(0, self.rows-1)            
                if [x,y] not in self.normalize_fill(fill):
                    self.board[x][y] = 3
                    self.food        = [x,y]
                    return
            

        
        def show_board(self, snake):
            
            board_ = ""
            for i in self.board:
                for j in i:
                    if j==1:
                        board_ += "@|"
                    elif j==2:

                        if snake.dir == "UP":
                            board_ += "^|"
                        elif snake.dir == "LEFT":
                            board_ += "<|"
                        elif snake.dir == "RIGHT":
                            board_ += ">|"
                        elif snake.dir == "DOWN":
                            board_ += "˅|"

                    elif j==3:
                        board_ += "*|"
                    else:
                        board_ += " |"

                board_ += "\n"
                board_ += "".join(["_ "*self.col])
                board_ += "\n"
                
            print(board_)
```

**snake.py**

```py
from random import choice
from threading import Thread
import sys
import select
import tty
import termios

class Snake:
    
    def __init__(self, length, pos, direction, board_size):
    
        if length != len(pos):
            raise Exception("Length is not equal to the size of `pos`")
        self.len    = length
        self.pos    = pos
        self.dir    = direction
        self.last   = pos[-1]
        self.first  = pos[0]
        self.columns= board_size[0]
        self.rows   = board_size[1]
        self.init_l = length
        self.status = True

    def normalize_pos(self):
        return [ [p[0]%self.rows, p[1]%self.columns] for p in self.pos]

    def move_toward_direction(self, step = 1, increment_size=False):

        temp = self.last[:]
        if self.dir.upper() == "UP":
            temp[0] -= 1
            if self.check(temp):
                self.pos.append(temp)
            else:
                self.__lost()

        elif self.dir.upper() == "DOWN":
            temp[0] += 1
            if self.check(temp):
                self.pos.append(temp)
            else:
                self.__lost()

        elif self.dir.upper() == "RIGHT":
            temp[1] += 1

            if self.check(temp):
                self.pos.append(temp)
            else:
                self.__lost()

        elif self.dir.upper() == "LEFT":
            temp[1] -= 1

            if self.check(temp):
                self.pos.append(temp)
            else:
                self.__lost()

        else:
            raise Exception(f"Direction not correct!: {self.dir}")

        if not increment_size :
            self.pos.remove(self.first)
            self.first = self.pos[0]
        else:
            self.len += 1
        self.first = self.pos[0]
        self.last  = self.pos[-1]

        
    
    def check(self, tmp):
        
        if tmp not in self.normalize_pos() and tmp not in self.pos:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def rand_direction(self):
        
        counter = 0

        while True:
            
            tmp = choice(["UP","RIGHT","LEFT","DOWN"])
            #chcs = [i for i in ["UP","RIGHT","LEFT","DOWN"] if self.check(i)]
            temp = self.last[:]
            if tmp == "UP"     :
                temp[0] -= 1

            elif tmp == "DOWN" :
                temp[0] += 1

            elif tmp == "RIGHT":
                temp[1] += 1

            elif tmp == "LEFT" :
                temp[1] -= 1

            else:
                raise Exception(f"Direction not correct!: {tmp}")
     
            if self.check(temp):
                self.dir = tmp
                return
            counter += 1
            if counter > 32:
                raise Exception("No movement is possible")


    def check_arrow_keys(self):
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
        try:
            tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin.fileno())
            while 1:
                if self.__isData() or self.status:
                    c = sys.stdin.read(3)
                    if c == '\x1b[A':         
                        if self.dir != "DOWN":
                            self.dir = "UP"
                    elif c == '\x1b[B':
                        if self.dir != "UP":
                            self.dir = "DOWN"
                    elif c == '\x1b[D':
                        if self.dir != "RIGHT":
                            self.dir = "LEFT"
                    elif c == '\x1b[C':
                        if self.dir != "LEFT":
                            self.dir = "RIGHT"
                    else:
                        pass
                else:
                    return

        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
                
    def __isData(self):
        return select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0) == ([sys.stdin], [], [])

    def __lost(self):
        self.status = False
```

also this is [link](https://github.com/Riahiamirreza/snake_game) of project on github. If you enjoyed the project, please give me star on github :D

**Edit:**
I noticed that if I run the program on the tmux, it will looks very better (It does not blink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, nice game! It plays pretty smoothly. The code looks decent as-is, which is why I'm going more in depth--high level, no improvements are really needed.

I'll go through by file, since it's split up.

### General comments

- Read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
- Be consistent about using blank lines. Don't leave a blank after a function `def`.
- Add type annotations
- Remove debugging code and commented-out code.
- I had trouble figuring out what functions did and didn't handle--I had to guess too much. Partly this is naming, partly it's lack of docstring or comments, and partly it's file organization. Also, it's just hard for a medium-sized game like this.
- Add docstrings to your methods to explain what each one does. Remember to explain the method in terms of "when would I want to call this?" rather than "what does it do inside?"
- In a couple places, you used `while True` loops. Try to use a more specific condition if you can, because then the reader can immediately read it and say "oh, the loop ends when..."

### User Testing

I tested this out. Some notes:

- Very clean visuals (although not all the characters display in my font).
- Movement feels silky smooth on my computer.
- It seems like the heart is drawn over the snake for a while after you eat it
- Once you die, you have to press a key to exit.
- I managed to wiggle the snake around and get a score of 0 somehow at the start. There may be race conditions in the threading.
- Overall looks cool!

### main.py

- Looks good.

### game.py

- Pass the same parameters you would to `new_game` to `__init__` instead, and remove `new_game`.
- Take the entire contents of the `run` loop. Split these into `get_input`, `do_tick`, and `update_display`. Right now there is no input processing in `game.py` which is a little confusing for someone trying to understand how it gets done.
- Have `board.show_board` return a board, and print it here. Try to put all your print statements in one file.
- Change the `run` loop to `while self.snake.alive` for clarity (change from `.status` to `.alive` for this reason)

### board.py

- I would say this is the file that needs the most improvement, but I don't have great answers as to how.
- Generally, this could use more separation between displaying the board, vs tracking the game state.
- Add a docstring to each method. In particular: `board_init`, `food_process`, `normalize_fill`, `check_food`, `put_food` all need one to figure out what they do. Even `show_board` is a little fuzzy in that I don't know if it will clear the screen or print the score
- There are too many blank lines
- Don't use hardcoded values 1 to 3 for board contents. Instead, use an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)
- Initialization:

  - I don't know what `board.fill` is based on the name, or `board.first`.
  - Rename `board.food` to `board.food_pos`
- `board_init` sounds like it should be called exactly once, at startup, but instead it's called every game tick. I'm not sure what it does.
- I don't know what `board.normalize_fill` or `snake.normalize_pos` do based on the name.
- Rename `check_food` to `is_food_on_board`. Make it a one-liner.
- Rename `put_food` to `place_random_food`. This is a good use of `while True`.
- In `show_board`, use the names `x,y` or `row,column` instead of `i,j`.

### snake.py

- Define an ENUM of directions
- Your initialization process is good. The variables are clear, but I think they could be trimmed or renamed in some cases.

  - You don't need `self.init_l`.
  - Change `snake.status` to `snake.alive`.
  - Change `first` and `last` to `head` and `tail`, which are clear for a snake. Then delete `head` and `tail`, because it's bad to have two variables that can be out of sync--if you want, `@property` might be a good fit instead.
  - Change `pos` to something like `occupied_squares` because it's not clear it's a list from the name.
- Add a docstring to `normalize_pos` and `check`, and `__isData`.
- `move_toward_direction` is too repetitive, shrink it. Remove the unused `step` parameter as well.
- Rename `self.__lost()` to `self.lose()` or `self.alive = False`. Prefer present tense action verbs for method names.
- Remove `rand_direction`, which looks like unused testing code.
- Move `check_arrow_keys` elsewhere, such as into `game.py`.

Comment: Thanks for your points. Very nice comments.